# How to return to beginning of program - java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having trouble getting my code to return to the beginning of the code and restart when confirm is not equal to 1. I have tried the return function but it just repeats confirmed constantly and I'm not sure what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int optionNumber = 0;
        int numberOfTickets = 0;
        int confirm = 0;
        int totalAmount = 0;

        int[] priceArray;
        priceArray = new int[3];
        priceArray[0] = 18;
        priceArray[1] = 36;
        priceArray[2] = (int) 32.50; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("\t" + "@@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@");
        System.out.println("\t" + "\t" + "MAIN MENU" + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Zoo has the following ticketing options" + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t" + "1 = Child (4-6 yrs");
        System.out.println("\t" + "2 = Adult (16+ yrs");
        System.out.println("\t" + "3 = Senior (60+ yrs" + "\n");

        System.out.println("Enter your option:" );
        optionNumber=input.nextInt();

         if(optionNumber == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child");
            numberOfTickets=input.nextInt();
        } else if (optionNumber == 2){
            System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult");
            numberOfTickets=input.nextInt();
        } else {
             System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior");
             numberOfTickets=input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
        confirm=input.nextInt();

        if (confirm ==1) {
            System.out.println("confirmed");
        } else {

        }



        if(optionNumber == 1) {
            totalAmount=priceArray[0]*numberOfTickets;
            System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + totalAmount);

        } else if (optionNumber == 2) {
            totalAmount=priceArray[1]*numberOfTickets;
            System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + totalAmount);

        } else {
            totalAmount=(int) ((double) priceArray[2]*numberOfTickets);
            System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + totalAmount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implement a conditional loop

Comment: Put some thought on using a `do-while` loop

Answer (score 3):

You could build a loop around it. Something like this (removed some code, but the idea how it should look like should be clear):

```
boolean chooseOption = true;
    while (chooseOption) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //print menu
        System.out.println("\t" + "@@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@");
        //TODO Your code 

        if (confirm == 1) {
            System.out.println("confirmed");
            // finish option selection
            chooseOption = false;
        } else {
            //choseOption stays true, hence the menu will be reprinted
            System.out.println("Cancelled ticketing." + " Selected Option number: " + optionNumber);
        }
    }
```

Always try to transfer your problem into a number of tasks. In this case you want to show a menu as long as no successfull selection was made.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a [`do...while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop`, with the`while` checking the condition

For example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int confirm;
do {
    // everything in here will repeat
    // until the input is not equal to 1
    // so put your desired code here
    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
    confirm = input.nextInt();
} while (confirm != 1);
```

So everything within the `{` after `do` and until the `}` before `while` will repeat as long as the user does not enter `1`.